# Honor 8 bricked after batter replacement

Tags: battery

I replaced the battery myself.
After finished, I trun on the phone, it vibrates once and the screen light up a little (hardly see it) but cannot boot. When I press and hold the power button, it turns off but on again automatically with the same phenomenon. What did I do wrong? I can charge the battery (the LED changed from yellow to green).

Comment: i guess you have damaged screen when opened the case